# seasonal plot Error in data.frame(y = as.numeric(x)) arguments imply differing number of rows:

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

here is my Code:

```
    month year GrandTotal   Date         
1     6  2014   15172331    2014-06-30
2     7  2014   24381383    2014-07-31
3     8  2014   24351338    2014-08-31
...
46     3  2018   85980914    2018-03-31
47     4  2018   72723488    2018-04-30


y <- ts(briskaranged, start=2014, frequency=12)
library(ggplot2)
#ploting of variables
autoplot(y) + 
labs(x ="Date", y = "GrandTotal", title = "Amount, ggplot2")
#seasonalplot
ggseasonplot(y, year.labels=TRUE, year.labels.left=TRUE) +
ylab("amount") +
ggtitle("Seasonal plot: amount transaction per day")
```

but compiler show error

> Error in data.frame(y = as.numeric(x), year = trunc(time(x)), cycle = 
>        as.numeric(cycle(x)),  : 
>        arguments imply differing number of rows: 235, 47

Comment: Best to run line by line and find out when this error first occurs. From your post, it's not clear when it does. Also could you provide  a sample of `briksaranged` using `dput`? Perhaps run a `traceback` call? Could you also name your `ts` something else rather than `y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
y <- ts(briskaranged$GrandTotal, start=2014, frequency=12)
library(ggplot2)
#ploting of variables
autoplot(y) + 
labs(x ="Date", y = "GrandTotal", title = "Amount, ggplot2")
#seasonalplot
ggseasonplot(y, year.labels=TRUE, year.labels.left=TRUE) +
ylab("amount") +
ggtitle("Seasonal plot: amount transaction per day")
```